# Spring MVC + eclipse + STS

Tags: spring, eclipse

I have installed Spring MVC tools and when I create spring mvc project, I have few errors in my pom.xml. There are three errors:

[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshot of the error. You can copy pasy your error messages to your post.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Failure to transfer com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org pom.xml /TEST line 1 Maven Configuration Problem

Comment: Please edit your post so that errors are visible in details

Answer (score 2):

You have some Jars that are not correctly downloaded on your local repository by Maven due to a connection issue, try to do `mvn -U install` or delete your local repository `${username_directory}/.m2` and do `maven update`.

Comment: I am having similar issues.. I don't think I have maven installed at all.. spring (in 2020) uses these mvnw files to run the demos... should I install maven? Its not mentioned anywhere in the quickstart guides...

Comment: I deleted the m2 folder and ran ./mvnw spring-boot:run in the project folder and the error on the POM is now gone. This is for the 2020 version of the Spring Quickstarts.

Comment: It worked fine on the command line then, but eclipse was showing some other errors, which were fixed with ' ./mvnw eclipse:eclipse' and that sorted out eclipse as well.. now its all working fine. So, basically, Messaouds answer here is completely correct..